# JQuery - .append() doesnt move the rest of code

Tags: jquery, html, append

i've these div on my html page :

```
// CSS
.trackon{width:710px; height:26px; color:#CCCCCC; font-weight:bold; float:left;}
.trackoff{display:none;}

// HTML
<div class="trackon" id="trackline1">Line 1</div>
<div class="trackon" id="trackline2">Line 2</div>
<div class="trackon" id="trackline3">Line 3</div>
<div class="trackoff" id="trackline4">Line 4</div>
<div class="trackoff" id="trackline5">Line 5</div>
```

with my own function addTrack(1) i want to append (for example) Line 5 between 1 and 2. so i make this function :

```
function addTrack(param) {
    $("#trackline5").removeClass().addClass('trackon');
    $("#trackline"+param).append($("#trackline5").html());
}
```

the problem is that this append doesnt move the other div down. That div (the one with Line 5) will displayed overlapped at the end of div with Line 1.

where im wrong? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you want [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) (which places elements *after* one another) rather than [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) (which places elements *inside* one another).  Secondly, don't bother with `html()`, just use the element itself:

```
function addTrack(param) {
    $("#trackline5").removeClass().addClass('trackon')
        .insertAfter("#trackline"+param);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` returns the inner content of its selection, not the tag itself.  So you're not getting your whole div appended, just the text contents.

Comment: yeah...so what i have to append?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to move the containers and not take #trackline5's content and add it to #trackline1, you'll need a different approach - by appending `$("#trackline5").html()`, you're only appending its contents - not the container.  You'd want to do something similar to the following:

```
function addTrack(param) {
    // Get the original element
    var $trackline5 = $('#trackline5');
    // We need a copy
    var $el = $trackline5.clone();
    // Remove the original from the DOM
    $trackline5.remove();
    // Insert the new element after the specified one
    $('#trackline' + param).after($trackline5);
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way which simply moves line 5.

```
function addTrack(param) {
    $("#trackline5").removeClass('trackoff').addClass('trackon').after($("#trackline" + param));
}
```